# Bootstrap - sticky/fixed navbar when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I’d like to create a navbar like this one: http://bartiistudio.tk/noxilie/onepage/index.html

Well, I use **stickUp jQuery script** but my navbar doesn’t work Wery well. I don’t know how to fix it.

And here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/792/

stickUp code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
        $(document).ready( function() {
         //enabling stickUp on the '.navbar-wrapper' class
         $('.navbar-wrapper').stickUp();
         });
});
```

Comment: the stickUp script changed the `navbar-wrapper` position from `relative` to `fixed`. Set a `width` to fix this problem.

Comment: Oh, yes I see now. Well width fix my problem. Thank you verymuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your problem is the `navbar-wrapper` not occupying the full width. You just need to set it `width:100%`. The stickUp changed the position of the navbar from `relative` to `fixed` so that caused the problem.

If all you need to do is just stick the navbar on top why not create your own script.

It's fun and easy :D

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var $stick = $('.navbar-wrapper');

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

        if(scrollTop >= $stick.offset().top){
            $stick.css({'position':'fixed'});
        }else{
            $stick.css({'position':'relative'});
        }
    });
});
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/52VtD/794/)

Comment: Yeah, I see how to handle it. And about own script I didn't know how to script because I'm a begginer. :P Thank you very much for help!